# asp.net Regular Expression Validator with Required Field Validator

Tags: asp.net, validation

My problem is that i want to get the error on the same place.

```
<td>
   <asp:TextBox> ...</asp:TextBox>
   <br />
      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
          ErrorMessage=""please enter 9 digis only" ...>
      </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
          ErrorMessage="this can't be blank" ...>
      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
```

i attached an image with the output, look and the red messages this is the validators.
i want that the error messages will be at the same place since just one error can be on.
thanks for helpers (and for who tries).

[image: the output of the code]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `Display=Dynamic` property to both the validators.

**[Further Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.display%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

Set the display attribute of the validators to "Dynamic".

Answer (score 2):

Use Display="Dynamic", try this:

```
<td>
    <asp:TextBox> ...</asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
        ErrorMessage="Please enter 9 digits only" Display="Dynamic" ...>
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
        ErrorMessage="this can't be blank" Display="Dynamic" ...>
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
```